# Mock De autenticação na dao

Tags: c#, testes-de-unidade

```
_usuario = CriaUsuario(new Login("Roberto"), new Senha("Senha"));

        var dao = new Mock<IUsuarioDao>();
        dao.Setup(d => d.Autenticar(It.IsAny<Login>(), It.IsAny<Senha>())).Returns(_usuario);


        var usuario = dao.Object.Autenticar(new Login("Roberto"), new Senha("Senha"));
```

Oque quero saber e se vale a pena fazer esse tipo de teste?
Porque eu olhando assim, prefiro fazer o teste acessando o banco de dados porque ai testaria a query

enfim.. qual a melhor maneira?

Comment: Não sei se entendi qual sua dificuldade. Isto está no seu código normal? Me parece errado. Não deve aletrar seu código normal para produzir testes. E os testes devem testar exatamente o que o código deveria fazer. Seu *mock* deveria funcionar como se fosse o banco de dados e fazer todas verificações se está tudo ok com dados e ambiente controlados. É fácil fazer isto? Não, mas as pessoas não contam sobre isso. Vale a pena fazer teste unitário? Depende de vários fatores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

São tipos de testes diferentes.

O primeiro, usando *mocks*, é um teste de unidade. O seu propósito é testar a lógica/regra que o método implementa.

O segundo é um teste de integração. O propósito é testar a integração dessa parte do sistema com outro sistema, neste caso o banco de dados.

Se vale a pena fazer os testes, não sei, só você pode qualificar a importância deles e quantificar o custo/beneficio de os fazer.

Se deve fazer o primeiro, o segundo ou os dois, deve escolher o nível de teste certo para a situação em causa.
Uma classe de negócio deve ser testada de maneira isolada, já o DAO (talvez)precise ser testado junto com o banco de dados.

Comment: No meu caso desenvolvo com nhibernate, e interessante testar as DAO/Repositorios ? Testes então na maioria dos casos usa-se para testar Regras somente.. Visto que DAO teoricamente e para ser simplesmente classes de acesso a banco de dados e retorno tratado dos dados, bom e isso que entendi?

Comment: Regras são normalmente testadas usando *mocks*, incluindo os objectos retornados do banco(testes de unidade). Por outro lado, neste caso, os testes de integração são usados para testar se a interacção com o banco está a ser "bem feita", por exemplo se as *queries* retornam os objectos(reais) desejados.

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado